# Referencing subordinate equations

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, subequations

I have this equation in my paper:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:pv-omega}
        \hat{p} = pv \ll j\Omega \quad \Rightarrow \quad \gamma=2,\\
        \hat{p} = pv \gg j\Omega \quad \Rightarrow \quad \gamma=0.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

Which produce this result:

[image: result]

Now, I would like use `\eqref` for link to it. There is a way to define two labels in the same equation, one for (10a) and one for (10b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another label after the `\\`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:pv-omega}
        \hat{p} = pv \ll j\Omega \quad \Rightarrow \quad \gamma=2,\\
\label{eq:pv-omega2}
        \hat{p} = pv \gg j\Omega \quad \Rightarrow \quad \gamma=0.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

I solved \ref{eq:pv-omega}, but not \ref{eq:pv-omega2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works also with `\eqref`.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni Ah, I didn't think of that, but good to know it works! :D